# Use a specified column of one data.frame within a list of data.frames in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I want to subtract the "response" column of a certain data.frame from a list of data.frames in R. Below is a subset of the data, and I want to use the "response" of B1.xls as a control, from which all the other "response" columns (A1.xls and A2.xls) are subtracted. Any suggestions to achieve it in a fast way? Thank you.

```
$A1.xls
    time   response
1 1320.0 0.00978786
2 1320.2 0.01236774
3 1320.4 0.01582583
4 1320.6 0.01947132
5 1320.8 0.02356580
6 1321.0 0.02786478

$A2.xls
    time   response
1 1320.0 0.00792504
2 1320.2 0.01079251
3 1320.4 0.01420215
4 1320.6 0.01848047
5 1320.8 0.02318325
6 1321.0 0.02836512

$B1.xls
    time   response
1 1320.0 0.00380097
2 1320.2 0.00515638
3 1320.4 0.00658969
4 1320.6 0.00803828
5 1320.8 0.00980306
6 1321.0 0.01187936
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R option using simple `for` loop

```
for (k in seq_along(lst)) {
  if (names(lst)[k] != "B1.xls") {
    lst[[k]]$response <- lst[[k]]$response - lst[["B1.xls"]]$response
  }
}
```

Comment: Neat. Simple and Useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An option is `lapply`.  Assuming that we want to only update the `list` elements with names that starts with "A", use `lapply` to loop over the subset of the `list` based on the `grep` on the `names`, then use `transform` to update the `response` by subtracting from the 'response' column from 'B1.xls' and assign it back to the subset `list`

```
nm1 <- grep("^A\\d+\\.xls", names(lst1))
#or
nm1 <- setdiff(names(lst1), "B1.xls")

lst1[nm1] <- lapply(lst1[nm1], transform,
          response = response - lst1$B1.xls$response)
```

NOTE: Here, we assume that all the `list` elements have the same number of rows

---

or we can use `tidyverse` approach with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
map_if(lst1, .p = str_detect(names(lst1), "^A\\d+\\.xls$"), ~
       .x %>%
             mutate(response = response - lst1$B1.xls$response))
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(A1.xls = structure(list(time = c(1320, 1320.2, 1320.4, 1320.6, 
1320.8, 1321), response = c(0.00978786, 0.01236774, 0.01582583, 
0.01947132, 0.0235658, 0.02786478)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6")), A2.xls = structure(list(time = c(1320, 
1320.2, 1320.4, 1320.6, 1320.8, 1321), response = c(0.00792504, 
0.01079251, 0.01420215, 0.01848047, 0.02318325, 0.02836512)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6")), B1.xls = structure(list(time = c(1320, 
1320.2, 1320.4, 1320.6, 1320.8, 1321), response = c(0.00380097, 
0.00515638, 0.00658969, 0.00803828, 0.00980306, 0.01187936)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6")))
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you so much! BTW, for `nm1`, please only use `nm1 <- setdiff(names(lst1), "B1.xls")` since there might be other letters involved. 
`

Comment: for the second solution, we need one modification: `library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
cont.name <- 'B1.xls'
map_if(lst1, 
       .p = names(lst1) != cont.name, 
       ~.x %>%mutate(response = response - lst1[[cont.name]]$response)) `

Comment: it seems that we only can select ONE correct solution. Your solution is right and neat. I just chose the one easier to understand by most R users. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @sophia It's okay.  Thank you for the  update

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`purrr::update_list`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/list_modify.html):

```r
library(purrr)

lst1 %>%
  update_list(A1.xls = ~ A1.xls - B1.xls,
              A2.xls = ~ A2.xls - B1.xls)
```

Comment: Thank you. I only need to subtract the "response" column. In addition, in the "big data" settings, it is inconvenient to update one by one. But still thank you for the solution. I did not know the `update_list` function until now.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map()`:

```
control_df_name <- "B1.xls"

c(Map(function(x){x$response <- x$response - lst1[[control_df_name]]$response; x}, 
    lst1[names(lst1) != control_df_name]), lst1[control_df_name])[names(lst1)]
```

Comment: Not sure the solution is right. Could you please make some comments on it?  Thank you.

Comment: @sophia You were correct, I had forgotten to assign the result back to x$response in the anonymous function Mapped over the list, please see the edit above.

Comment: Wonderful solution :-)